# No language option for creating a new Empty Activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was trying to create a new project in the newer Android Studio. When I select the `Empty Activity`, I no longer see a `language` option (Java vs Kotlin) there. However, it exists for other Activities (No Activity, Basic View Activity, etc).

Why is that? Anything changed recently or it's a bug maybe?

[image]

Comment: When was the last time you used Android Studio?

Comment: 1.5 years ago...

Comment: Based on the description "Create a new empty activity with Jetpack Compose", looks like it's forced to use Kotlin because Jetpack Compose only works with Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "Empty Activity" use "Empty View Activity" while creating a new project.

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain why

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new project, if you do not see the Language selection option, you have selected Empty Activity instead of Empty View Activity option.
If you cannot create a java project in android studio You have selected Empty Activity instead of Empty View Activity